# Player change scale with OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im creating MovingPlatform and i want that my player move with platform together.

with this code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        collision.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        collision.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
```

With this code player is moving with platform, but his size become smaller on this platform. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this override of `SetParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

```
collision.transform.SetParent(parentTransform, worldPositionStays: true);
```

Comment: I cannot use "parentTransform" - not exist. I tied to do `collision.transform.SetParent(transform, worldPositionStays: true);`   but anyway player become small on platform

Comment: Use any transform you want. The key point is to use override with `worldPositionStays: true`

Comment: with `worldPositionStays: true` nothing changes. Player still small when on platform.

Comment: Oh, sorry, was my fault. Scale of platform was 0.5, thats why player also transform to 0.5. Many Thanks for your help.